# Simple understanding of https protocol

Tags: ssl, https, tls1.2

Out of curiosity, can someone help explain to me what will theoretically happen if a uri of protocol `https` ([TLS 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346)) is accessed on a primitive browser that predates TLS 1.1? E.g. a primitive feature phone with GPRS connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server only support TLS1.1 and a browser without TLS1.1 try to connect, the connection will fail.

Usually servers supports TLS1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 : Modern browsers can use the 1.2 version, but older ones can still connect on the 1.0 version.

https://ssllabs.com can help you see it (it tests websites to determine which browser can connect to it and the level of security of the connexion)